# How to plot Quarterly and Year-to-Date values in ggplot?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, bar-chart

### Raw data

```
structure(list(attainment_target = c(7.5, 15), quarter_2022 = c("Q1", 
"Q2"), total_attainment = c(2, 4), percent_attainment = c(0.2666, 
0.2666)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))


Quarter    | Target  | Attainment 

2022-01-01    7.5          2
2022-04-01    15           4
```

### Scenario

I would like to plot a ggplot (geom_col or geom_bar) with Quarter as x-axis and Attainment as y-axis with Target as a horizontal dash line that shows how far off I am from that value.

However, I am having trouble plotting YTD (Total attainment given # of quarters) in the same plot. Here is an example of how I used dplyr to create new field that shows calculated YTD value:

### Desired output

```
Quarter    | Target  | Attainment  | YTD. | % Attainment 

2022-01-01    7.5          2         2       27
2022-04-01    15           4         6       40
```

Which is the best way to plot this via ggplot in R? Here is my current approach but having trouble incorporating all the above:

```
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(YTD_TOTAL = sum(total_attainment)) %>%
    mutate(YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT = sum(total_attainment) / max(attainment_target))


ggplot(data = df1, aes(fill=quarter_2022, x=attainment_target, y=total_attainment, color = quarter_2022, palette = "Paired",
label = TRUE,
position = position_dodge(0.9)))
```

Comment: Can you please share your raw data in the form of code we can run, e.g. by pasting in the output of running `dput(df1)` into the body of your question?

Comment: @JonSpring updated question and included the dataformat!

Comment: I think you meant / used `mutate(YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT = cumsum(total_attainment) / max(attainment_target))` and `mutate(YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT = YTD_TOTAL/ attainment_target)`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you have in mind but here are some of the pieces you might want to use:

```
df %>%
  mutate(YTD_TOTAL = cumsum(total_attainment)) %>%
  mutate(YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT = YTD_TOTAL/ attainment_target) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(quarter_2022, total_attainment)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = YTD_TOTAL), fill = NA, color = "gray20") +
  geom_text(aes(y = YTD_TOTAL, label = scales::percent(YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT)),
            vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray70", color = "gray20") +
  geom_text(aes(label = total_attainment),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(quarter_2022)) - 0.4, 
                   xend = as.numeric(as.factor(quarter_2022)) + 0.4,
                   y = attainment_target, yend = attainment_target),
               linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! is there any way to show a key that breaks down the horizontal values to the right or the graph?